# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'city' of undefined for ab.address.city

Tags: angular, typescript, class, model, angular9

I would like to inform that I am new to angular. I am trying to read a json file with a service and assign the data to classes and show data in the template.
All is working but I have found that it is reporting typeError in the console of the browser.
[image]

--about.service.ts--

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { About } from './about';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AboutService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  private _url:string="/assets/data/about.json";
  getAboutInfo2(){
    /*return [{"id":1,"name":"andrew","age":32}];*/
    return this.http.get<About>(this._url);
  }
  getAboutInfo():Observable<About>{
    /*return this.http.get<About[]>(this._url).(data=>new About());*/
    return this.http.get<About>(this._url);
    }
}
```

--about.component.ts--

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AboutService } from '../about.service';
import { About } from '../about';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _aboutService: AboutService) { }
  public variable: string="I am imtiaj";
  public ab:About=new About();
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._aboutService.getAboutInfo()
      .subscribe(data=> this.ab=data);

  }
}
```

--about.component.html--

```
      <div class="container-fluid p-0">

        <section class="resume-section p-3 p-lg-5 d-flex align-items-center" id="about">
          <div class="w-100">
            <h1 class="mb-0">{{ab.firstName}}
              <span class="text-primary">{{ab.lastName}}</span>
            </h1>
            <div class="subheading mb-5">{{ab.address.city}},{{ab.address.country}},
              <a href="mailto:{{ab.email}}">{{ab.email}}</a>
            </div>
            <p class="lead mb-5">{{ab.objective}}</p>
            <div class="social-icons">
              <a href="{{ab.links.linkedIn}}">
                <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="{{ab.links.gitHub}}">
                <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="{{ab.links.twitter}}">
                <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="{{ab.links.instagram}}">
                <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="{{ab.links.facebook}}">
                <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>

        <hr class="m-0">
      </div>
```

--about.ts--

```
export  class About{

     id: number;
     firstName: string;
     lastName: string;
     address:AboutAddress;
     email:string;
     objective:string;
     links:AboutLinks;
}


export class AboutAddress{
     city: string;
     country: string;
}
export class AboutLinks{
     linkedIn:string;
     gitHub:string;
     twitter:string;
     instagram:string;
     facebook:string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a best practice, you can get rid of this error by using safe navigation operator (?)

```
 <div class="subheading mb-5">{{ab?.address?.city}},{{ab?.address?.country}},
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  
I have implemented you suggestion and the errors are gone.
Can you explain why did the errors come? And what actually ? does here?

Comment: safe navigation operator is l to protect against null and undefined values in property paths.It returns value of the object path if it exists, else it returns the null value.

Comment: that is useful.
without using the question mark, how can i solve it otherwise?

Comment: you need to make sure the values are not empty, tahts the way

Comment: As i mentioned i am new to angular.
I have assigned the values to the properties, How can i make it sure for the compiler?

Comment: you need to make sure the rest api returns the contract will filled data;

Comment: If you want to get rid of `foo?.bar`, just add a wrapper in your HTML `<ng-container *ngIf="ab && ab.address">YOUR CONTENT</ng-container>`, then within this container you will not have to worry about `ab` or `ab.address` being potentially undefined.

Comment: thanks for your reply Philipp. I have one confusion. Why did not the error happened with ab.firstname? it only happens for object type properties such as ab.address.city or ab.links.linkedIn.

Comment: Because the first name is not empty!